# В чем причина различного поведения библиотеки в проектах?

Tags: c#, dll

У меня происходит какая-то магия, которую я не могу познать.

Есть библиотека с одним единственным открытым методом. Библиотека выполняет печать указанного PDF файла на принтере с указанным именем.

Так вот если, я создаю консольное приложение, подключаю библиотеку и вызываю данный метод - то все хорошо.

Но в основном проекте(присутствует иная бизнес логика), библиотека печатает файл криво(поворачивает его на 90 градусов), при абсолютно тех же файлах и на том же принтере.

Прикладываю код библиотеки:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer;

namespace PdfPrinter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Принтер - печатает PDF файлы
    /// </summary>
    public static class Printer
    {
        public static PrinterSettings.StringCollection InstalledPrinters => PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters;

        /// <summary>
        /// Печать файла
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pdfFile"></param>
        public static void PrintFile(string pdfFile, string printerName)
        {
            try
            {

                // Генерируем изображения с помощью Ghostscript
                List<Image> images = GenerateImages(pdfFile, 600, 600);


                // Дебаг код - для проверка что изображения сгенерированны нормально.
                string dir = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "TEST");
                if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                File.Copy(pdfFile, Path.Combine(dir, Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetFileName(pdfFile), "pdf")), true);
                for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++) images[i].Save(Path.Combine(dir, i + ".jpg"));
                Process.Start(dir);

                // Печатаем изображения
                ImagesPrinting(printerName, images);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new PrinterException("Произошла ошибка при печати", ex);
            }
        }       
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Печатает картинки
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="printerName"></param>
        /// <param name="inputFile"></param>
        private static void ImagesPrinting(string printerName, List<Image> images)
        {
            PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
            printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
            
            int curPage = 0;
            printDoc.PrintPage += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(images[curPage++], e.PageBounds);

                if (curPage >= images.Count)
                    e.HasMorePages = false;
                else
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
            };

            bool end = false;
            printDoc.EndPrint += (s, e) => end = true;
            
            printDoc.QueryPageSettings += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.PageSettings.Landscape = true;
            };

            printDoc.Print();

            while (!end)
                Application.DoEvents();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Генерация изображений
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputFile"></param>
        /// <param name="xDPI"></param>
        /// <param name="yDPI"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static List<Image> GenerateImages(string inputFile, int xDPI, int yDPI)
        {
            List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

            GhostscriptRasterizer rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer();
            rasterizer.Open(inputFile, Properties.Resources.gsdll32);
            rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-dInterpolateControl=0");
            rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-sPAPERSIZE=A4");
            rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-dNOTRANSPARENCY");

            for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum < rasterizer.PageCount; pageNum++)
                images.Add(rasterizer.GetPage(xDPI, yDPI, pageNum + 1));
            rasterizer.Dispose();

            return images;
        }       
    
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Исключение печати
    /// </summary>
    public class PrinterException : Exception
    {
        public PrinterException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Вот консольная программа вызывающая библиотеку - работает хорошо.

```
namespace ClearPrint
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // в args[0] - путь к pdf-файлу
            PdfPrinter.Printer.PrintFile(args[0], "Тут валидное имя принтера");
        }
    }
}
```

А вот метод основной программы, который вызывает PrintFile из библиотеки:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Метод обработки новых сообщений от URL-handler'а
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void NewMessageHandler(object s, string e)
    {
        // Для отладки, позволяет указать вместо ID файла для скачки, путь к имеющемуся файлу
        if (File.Exists(e))
        {
            // Печатаем файл
            Printer.PrintFile(e, Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterName);

            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // Качаем файл
            var response = API.DownloadFile(e);

            // Если файл получен
            if (response.success)
            {
                // Разворачиваем base64 в байты файла
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(response.data.pdf);

                string tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

                File.WriteAllBytes(tmpFile, data);

                // Печатаем файл
                Printer.PrintFile(tmpFile, Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterName);

                // Отчитываемся
                API.MarkFile(e);
            }
            // не удалось скачать файл
            else
            {
                Reporter.NewError("Не удалось получить файл.", null);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (ApiException ex)
        {
            Reporter.NewError("Не удалось получить файл.", ex);
            return;

        }
        catch (PrinterException ex)
        {
            Reporter.NewError("Не удалось распечатать файл", ex);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Reporter.NewError("Произошла не предвиденная ошибка.", ex);
            return;
        }

    }
```

А вот это работает криво (поворачивает картинку при печати). Не важно используем ли существующий файл(дебаг) или скачиваем файл по ID.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91249/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Comment: У меня была таже магия, я решил, но сейчас нет доступа на исходники. Удалось решить проблему? Если нет, то завтра посмотрю.